# ASP.NET Web API : What to return from API that adds new record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have a POST API that adds a records in a table called *Product*. On successful insert of record, what should API return in response body from one of the following?

**A.** Id of product that is inserted in table.

**B.** The entire record along with Product Id.

What is recommended as best practice?

I've seen some instances where developer return whole object that resembles record that was inserted (like case **B**). Doesn't it seem like wastage of bandwidth to return whole object while API consumer might only need Product Id?

What are pros and cons of **A** and **B**? Any resources explaining such things are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have basically explained the advantage of B, and the disadvantage of B, already.

Comment: it's all about requirement of the web api call. you will decide this on base of requirements

Comment: Entire record is common, also a Location header that contains a URL that will GET that record.

Comment: It depends a lot on the requirements of your application. Is confirmation required? Should the user be prevented from continuing on failure? Should there be an opportunity to correct? Do you *need* some details to come back?

Comment: What to return depends on requirement of the client of the API and preferences of the API provider. Do you have anything extra to be returned after the product is created? What is your client's requirements? Also if you return only id then the client will have to make another API call to get the details which is again bandwidth waste

Comment: A "201 Created" response is common, and quite appropriate. It should include a Location header pointing to the URL where a GET request can be made to retrieve the new resource. https://httpstatuses.com/201. Web API provides a CreatedAtRoute helper method for doing this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045604/can-anyone-explain-createdatroute-to-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by yourself and in the comments you have pretty much 2 options.

1. Some form of confirmation message
2. a ResultSet containing the inserted information

As I see this, it is highly dependant on the way you are handling Data on the other side of your application.

For example:
Our Application is using an Asp.Net Web API with an Angular Front-End which implements rudimentary Data-Handling to reduce the need of regular exchange of large Data Sets. When a Partial Set of Data is to be updated it's send and processed whole at the API.

The API then sends back either a 201 as a Success message or a 409 containing an Error-Set which is mapped to the Data-Display indicating which Data is corrupt or in conflict and needs review.

[@Daniel Perez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201805/8471295) and [@grahamesd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28951049/8471295) answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199872/best-practice-for-restful-post-response) Thread might interest you as well as [@Robert Harvey♦'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383302/8471295) suggestion to review other APIs for inspiration.

Returning the inserted Data has the advantage that you can check that it is correct.